# can not get history output when executed history by SSH command

Tags: linux, shell

for example:
when

```
ssh xxx@192.168.0.123 "histroy"
```

it get nothing,

but when

```
ssh xxx@192.168.0.123
```

and then

```
history
```

it get a lot.

any one tell me how to get the history by one line command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ssh xxx@192.168.0.123 'export HISTFILE=~/.bash_history; set -o history; history'
```

Comment: wow, works like magic!

Comment: @yeer `ssh xxx@192.168.0.123 "cat ~/.bash_history | nl"` also works, try that out.

Comment: Could you provide some explanation about what your code does?

Answer (score 0):

You can cat the file that the history command reads from and then number each line:

```
ssh xxx@192.168.0.123 "cat ~/.bash_history | nl"
```

Comment: yes, but it can not get the time stamps.

Comment: did not work :(

Comment: hi chown, i did not add any formatting, i wanna to see the output first, the formatting is secondary.

Answer (score 0):

```
ssh hostname 'HISTTIMEFORMAT="%d/%m/%y %T     ";HISTFILE=~/.bash_history; set -o history;echo "  command " ; history'
```

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Please consider adding some explanation for those not familiar with how this command works. Thanks for contributing.

Comment: This appears to be just the accepted answer plus some un-called-for bells and whistles.